# Change IntegratyError page on Flask and SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm doing a rental system with Flask and I have some registers on a data base like `Tenant`, `Owner` and `Immobile` with their *primary key* and some *foreign keys*.

When I try to clear a table with a *foreign key* I have this `IntegrityError`:

[image: IntegratyError]

**But I don't want to solve this error, I just want to change this page to another. How could I do that?**

This is my code:

```py
@app.route('/inquilino_delete/<id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def inquilino_delete(id):
    inquilino = Inquilino.query.get_or_404(id)
    print(id)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('inquilino/delete_inquilino.html', inquilino=inquilino)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if inquilino:
            db.session.delete(inquilino)
            db.session.commit()
            
            return redirect(url_for('show_all_inquilinos'))
        abort(404)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it with a try except sqlalchemy.exc import IntegrityError

```
def inquilino_delete(id):
    inquilino = Inquilino.query.get_or_404(id)
    print(id)
    
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('inquilino/delete_inquilino.html', inquilino=inquilino)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if inquilino:
            db.session.delete(inquilino)
            try:
                db.session.commit()
                return redirect(url_for('show_all_inquilinos'))
            except IntegrityError:
                flash('Você não pode excluir por ser uma chave estrangeira!')
                return redirect(url_for('show_all_inquilinos'))
        abort(404)
```